# Is it possible to change a Nuget package reference based on the targeted platform?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, nuget, 32bit-64bit

I am creating an application that uses the [Oracle Data Provider for .Net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html). Some of my clients will be running the application in a 32 bit environment, and others on a 64 bit architecture, so I need to provide two versions of the application.

The Oracle Data Provider comes in two different Nuget packages, one for [x86](https://nuget.org/packages/odp.net.x86/), the other for [x64](https://nuget.org/packages/odp.net.x64/).

Is there a way to set up Nuget to download or switch to the appropriate package source based on the project build configuration?  I'm hoping there's an easy way to simply switch my project configuration to build against the correct drivers, but I'm unable to discover if there's a way to make Nuget work in this scenario.

Comment: I have the same question - would like to know if anyone knows if this is possible - I've had problems with builds after switching from 32Bit to 64Bit especially when referencing the EntityFramework nuget package which comes in both 32Bit and 64Bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

Nuget package is just a DLL after all.
So like any DLL, you can use versioning to direct your application to use the right version.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I could download and extract the dlls from each package, but I want to be able to continue using Nuget to manage the packages. This may be a function of the fact that the two Nuget packages here have the exact same assembly names, so there just may not be a simple way to do what I'm trying to accomplish.